# Refactored code submits the form even after showing an alert

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following Javascript code which works fine and I have just shown how it is called in a form on submit without including form related details as it's not needed.

```js
            function affiliationcarKitCodechecks() {
        
     if(document.getElementsByName("affiliatedPrimary") !== null){
            let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("affiliatedPrimary");
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
             
                 if(checkboxes[i].value === "CED"){
                         let partOne = document.getElementById("partOne").value;
                     let partTwo = document.getElementById("partTwo").value;
                     partOne=partOne.trim();
                     partTwo=partTwo.trim();
                     if (partOne.length==0 && partTwo.length==0) {
                        alert("Please complete the partOne or AltId/Tattoo fields. This information is required ");
                        return false;
                     }
                    
                 }
            }
        }


            
        }
        
       var checkboxes =  document.getElementsByName('affiliatedSecondary');
      
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
             
                 if(checkboxes[i].value === "CED"){
                         let partOne = document.getElementById("partOne").value;
                     let partTwo = document.getElementById("partTwo").value;
                     partOne=partOne.trim();
                     partTwo=partTwo.trim();
                     if (partOne.length==0 && partTwo.length==0) {
                        alert("Please complete the partOne or AltId/Tattoo fields. This information is required ");
                        return false;
                     }
                    
                 }
            }
        }
    
        
        let doescarKitCodeExists = document.getElementById("carKitCode");
         //check for empty string
        if(doescarKitCodeExists.value !== ""){
            //check if the string equals carKitCode
            if(doescarKitCodeExists.value === "carKitCode") {
                let partOne = document.getElementById("partOne").value;
                let partTwo = document.getElementById("partTwo").value;
                partOne=partOne.trim();
                partTwo=partTwo.trim();
                if (partOne.length==0 && partTwo.length==0) {
                    alert("Please complete the partOne or partTwo fields. This information is required ");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        


        
    }
```

```html
<form id="orderForm" action="/mywebsite/car.htm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateOrderForm(this) && affiliationCEDchecks()" data-gtm-form-interact-id="0">
            </form>
```

I have refactored it like this by separating out the repetitive code into a separate function `checkEmptyFields()` as shown in the code snippet below.

Now, the problem is, when an alert is shown, my form would still submit which I don't want. My understanding is that `checkEmptyFields` is returning a false when an alert is shown and I'm not returning it inside my `if` blocks below. So do I need to return something like `return checkEmptyFields();` wherever I'm calling this function?

Here is my refactored javascript code:

```js
function checkEmptyFields () {
  let partOne = document.getElementById("partOne").value;
  let partTwo = document.getElementById("partTwo").value;
  
  partOne=partOne.trim();
  partTwo=partTwo.trim();
  
  if (partOne.length==0 && partTwo.length==0) {
    alert("Please complete the partOne or partTwo fields. This information is required ");
    return false;
  }
}

if(document.getElementsByName("affiliatedPrimary") !== null){
            let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("affiliatedPrimary");
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
             
                 if(checkboxes[i].value === "CED"){
                     checkEmptyFields();
                    
                 }
            }
        }


            
        }
        
       var checkboxes =  document.getElementsByName('affiliatedSecondary');
      
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
             
                 if(checkboxes[i].value === "CED"){
                     checkEmptyFields();
                    
                 }
            }
        }
    
        
        let doescarKitCodeExists = document.getElementById("carKitCode");
         //check for empty string
        if(doescarKitCodeExists.value !== ""){
            //check if the string equals carKitCode
            if(doescarKitCodeExists.value === "carKitCode") {
               checkEmptyFields();
            }
        }
        


        
    }
```

```html
<form id="orderForm" action="/mywebsite/car.htm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateOrderForm(this) && affiliationCEDchecks()" data-gtm-form-interact-id="0">
            </form>
```

Comment: In the original code, you're returning from the `affiliationcarKitCodechecks` function after the alert is shown. In the refactored code, you don't. You'll can change the `checkEmptyFields` to return `true` when the alert is not shown and use something like: `if (checkboxes[i].value === "CED" && !checkEmptyFields()) { return false; }`

Comment: @Titus Thanks. Is it okay to use something like this ? `if(checkboxes[i].value === "CED"){
   if(checkEmptyFields() === false){
   return false;
   }
                    
 }`

Comment: It seems to be working fine when I tested above change but not sure if that's a good way to handle this? Since I'm not returning `return true;` in my original code inside `affiliationcarKitCodechecks` function when alert is not shown, I thought of not doing that while making above change as well

Comment: If you don't use the return value from `affiliationcarKitCodechecks`, it doesn't matter. By the way, you can just store the return value of `checkEmptyFields` instead of executing it each time. Something like `let flag = checkEmptyFields()` and then `if (checkboxes[i].value === "CED" && flag === false)`

Comment: `If you don't use the return value from affiliationcarKitCodechecks, it doesn't matter` Could you explain why it still works even though I'm not returning true when alert is not shown?

Comment: Because you compare the return value using `=== false`, when the function doesn't return `false`, the default return value is `undefined`

Comment: So is it going to get evaluated as true in the onSubmit of my form `return validateOrderForm(this) && affiliationCEDchecks()` if first function returns true.